# Login Name in User Information List is in Lower Case

Tags: ad, user-information-list, user-profile-service-app

In AD, the login name is in upper case (example: CONTOSO\JANE.DOE). In the user profile found in the SharePoint User Profile Service Application, it's still in upper case. However, in the SharePoint User Information List, it's in lower case (example: contoso\jane.doe). Is this OOTB SharePoint behaviour that in the SharePoint User Information List, the login name will always be in lower case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the login name will always be in lower case in the user information list. Name and JobTitle for example will be in the correct casing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, Andreas!

Just to clarify, the login name that I'm referring to is the value found in the User Information List's "Account" field.

Based on my further testing, if the web application is claims-based, the login name is always in lower case. However, if the web application is classic, the login name is in the same case as what was used in AD.